# want to share a link to a www page by email, but when clicked by the receiver, has to go to some place middle

Tags: html, email

I want to share the below page with my friend by email, but when he clicks on the link, it has to go to section named *People*. No id for this section, looked at the source. Can it be done? Is there a trick?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology

Comment: It *does* have an `id`, the element is `<span class="mw-headline" id="People">People</span>`.  P.S. You could just right click on the `People` link in the Contents and copy the link.

Comment: Just wondering.. if there was no id.. can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people section does have an ID

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="People">People</span>
```

This link goes directly to the 'People' Section:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology#People

Answer (score 2):

Make use of anchors and send this link to your friend instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology#People

Notice the `#People`at the end.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks! Looks like only one can be accepted as the answer.